# Setup font size of different types to be the same

Tags: fonts, fontsize, fourier, mathcal

For mathematical documents i like using the `fourier` package with the `upright` option, however the symbols `\mathcal` produces are quite too quirky in my opinion, so I replaced them with the default font via `\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}` - however these symbols have a different font size than the `fourier` fonts.

Here is an example which shows that the caligraphic X is too big:

[image: different font sizes]

How can I reduce the size of `\mathcal` symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load the `cmsy` font scaled at .942 (computed by comparing the heights):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\DeclareFontFamily{OMS}{fcmsy}{\skewchar\font48 }
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{fcmsy}{m}{n}{%
         <-5.5> [.942] cmsy5     <5.5-6.5> [.942] cmsy6
      <6.5-7.5> [.942] cmsy7     <7.5-8.5> [.942] cmsy8
      <8.5-9.5> [.942] cmsy9     <9.5->  [.942] cmsy10
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{fcmsy}{b}{n}{%
       <-6> [.942] cmbsy5
      <6-8> [.942] cmbsy7
      <8->  [.942] cmbsy10
      }{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{fcmsy}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
$X\mathcal{X}$
\end{document}
```

[image]